# QtWebEngine debugging

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

Recently Qt introduced the `QtWebEngine` module. Is there a way to invoke developer tools and debug JavaScript code inside `QWebEngineView`? It was possible with `QWebView` using

```
page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled, true);
```

but I couldn't find any similar option in `QWebEngineView`.

Comment: It seems there is nothing in documentation about this possibility for QWebEngine. Hopefully it will appear in future versions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I just ran across this so I added it here for posterity.

It was just added to Qt 5.5 git.  You have to enable it via an environment variable `QTWEBENGINE_REMOTE_DEBUGGING=<port>`. You can put `0.0.0.0:<port>` if you are doing debugging of an embedded device and cant use the local console. Then you can point can connect to http://127.0.0.1: to get the debugger.  It will need to be a chromium based browser.  Do you have to use Chrome, or you can actually use the "quick nano browser" example if you want.

Comment: Did you try using QtWebEngine itself to host the debugger instead of an external Chromium based browser?

Comment: Yes that does work.  It just requires a bit more ram.  It seemed to work the exact same though.

Comment: Is anybody able to make this work with Qt 5.5.0 + Chrome 47 on Linux? It was working fine a couple of months ago, but now I just get a blank page when I select my page from the "Inspectable pages" list :-/. I'm guessing it's because the devtools protocol has changed in a backwards-incompatible way.

Comment: Huh, strangely this works when I build my app with an old Qt 5.5.0 beta I had lying around, but not with the final 5.5.0 release. Looks like a Qt regression.

Comment: @VickyChijwani Any update on this? Experience the same with Qt 5.7.

Comment: @vehsakul yes. If I remember correctly, I was making a mistake when I wrote that comment. The environment variable needs to be set before _any_ calls to Qt WebEngine functions, including functions in `QWebEngineSettings` et al - any calls like that will spawn the Chromium "zygote" process immediately, so new environment changes won't be picked up. You can actually observe the zygote process being spawned with a tool like `htop`, if you set your breakpoints correctly ;)

Comment: @vehsakul also, if there _were_ any bugs in the debugging protocol (I don't remember), I'm pretty sure they​ were fixed in Qt 5.5.1, because we shipped with that version.

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, one may embed [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) to get a JavaScript console and inspectors.

Just add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```

into the page. Pressing F12 will visualize the Firebug console.

Answer (score 3):

For PyQt5 the following snippet:

```py
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.webView, 100)

        self.webView.settings().setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
        self.webView.settings().setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)
        self.webView.settings().setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.ErrorPageEnabled, True)
        self.webView.settings().setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)



        dev_view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(dev_view, 100)
        self.webView.page().setDevToolsPage(dev_view.page())
```

Answer (score 2):

If your devtools view and page are in the same program，use qt function to directly navigate to page devtools instead of `http://localhost:port` whith is devtools index(have to select devtools of whitch page).

After `QTWEBENGINE_REMOTE_DEBUGGING` being set up

`>=5.13`:

```
void QWebEnginePage::setDevToolsPage(QWebEnginePage *devToolsPage)
```

`5.11~5.12`:

```
void QWebEnginePage::setInspectedPage(QWebEnginePage *page)
```

Sample `pyqt5.12`

```
dev_view = QWebEngineView()  # new web view
self.page().setDevToolsPage(dev_view.page())  # self is the source web view
```

Reference:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#setDevToolsPage

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#setInspectedPage

Answer (score 1):

From http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/03/17/qt-5-5-alpha-available/:

> The remote inspector can be used by either defining the env variable
>   QTWEBENGINE_REMOTE_DEBUGGING, or by supplying the
>   –remote-debugging-port command line argument. You can then point a
>   browser at the specified port and inspect your web content.

Answer (score 0):

look this：

The Chromium DevTools provide the ability to inspect and debug layout and performance issues of any web content

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#chromium-devtools