# DevTools in QtWebEngine?

Tags: qt, devtools, qwebkit, qt5.4, qtwebengine

Has anyone found a way to enable Chrome or Chrome-like DevTools for debugging JavaScript inside of QWebEngine in QT5.4?

It seems that this will be available in 5.5 and was available in QtWebKit.

Thanks!

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681141/qtwebengine-debugging