# Qt: Cannot invoke shared object methods/properties from javascript

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

I have tried exactly same as the answer of Vicky Chijwani for this question
[QT QWebEnginePage::setWebChannel() transport object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928444/qt-qwebenginepagesetwebchannel-transport-object)
 and everything fine but I cant able to invoke any methods or properties of jshelper.

kindly look at my code
**myclass.h**

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);
    void print();

    int num;

signals:

public slots:
};
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
 num=100;
}

void MyClass::print()
{
    QMessageBox bx;
    bx.exec();
}
```

**mywebengineview.h**

```
class MyWebEngineView : public QWebEngineView
{
public:
    MyWebEngineView(QWidget *parent);

    MyClass helper;
};
```

**mywebengineview.cpp**

```
MyWebEngineView::MyWebEngineView(QWidget *parent): QWebEngineView(parent)
{
    QWebChannel *channel = new QWebChannel(page());
    channel->registerObject(QStringLiteral("jshelper"), &helper);load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo("../html/index.html").absoluteFilePath()));
    page()->setWebChannel(channel);
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    view = new MyWebEngineView(this);
    view->setGeometry(10, 10, 500, 500);
    view->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo("../html/index.html").absoluteFilePath()));
}
```

**finally javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var jshelper;
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {
                alert('ok');
                // all published objects are available in channel.objects under
                // the identifier set in their attached WebChannel.id property

                jshelper = channel.objects.jshelper;
                alert( jshelper.num );
                jshelper.print();

            });
        });

        </script>
```

The problem is these two lines never executes properly

```
alert( jshelper.num ); // gives 'undefined' message
jshelper.print(); //will not work
```

what is wrong with my code, I am trying to fix this issue around 4 days but I couldn't able to fix it.

Comment: What does `console.log(channel.objects.jshelper)`, or `console.log(channel.objects)` say?

Comment: jshelper:__id__: "jshelper"__objectSignals__: Object__propertyCache__: ObjectdeleteLater: function () {destroyed: Objectconnect: function (callback) {disconnect: function (callback) {__proto__: ObjectobjectName: (...)get objectName: function () {set objectName: function (value) {objectNameChanged: ObjectpropertyUpdate: function (signals, propertyMap)signalEmitted: function (signalName, signalArgs)unwrapProperties: function ()unwrapQObject: function (response)__proto__: QObject

Comment: So no `num` or `print` functions clearly.

Comment: yes what i am missing..? i couldn't able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know under QWebKit, I had to make the members functions look like this:

```
public slots:
    Q_INVOKABLE void print();
```

Comment: thanks a ton man. qtwebengine also require Q_INVOKABLE. I never tried this. :( Now its working.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm providing a comment late, but if the function in question is declared in the slots section, you don't have to use Q_INVOKABLE.  Slightly less typing if there are several functions.

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);

slots:
    void print();
}
```