# Qt property has no notify signal updates in HTML will be broken

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

In the process of learning PyQT5 I came across this example

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

qwebchannel_js = QFile(':/qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js')
if not qwebchannel_js.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
    raise SystemExit(
        'Failed to load qwebchannel.js with error: %s' %
        qwebchannel_js.errorString())
qwebchannel_js = bytes(qwebchannel_js.readAll()).decode('utf-8')


def client_script():
    script = QWebEngineScript()
    script.setSourceCode(qwebchannel_js + '''
    new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {
        channel.objects.bridge.print('Hello world!');
    });
''')
    script.setName('xxx')
    script.setWorldId(QWebEngineScript.MainWorld)
    script.setInjectionPoint(QWebEngineScript.DocumentReady)
    script.setRunsOnSubFrames(True)
    return script


class WebPage(QWebEnginePage):
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, level, msg, linenumber, source_id):
        try:
            print('%s:%s: %s' % (source_id, linenumber, msg))
        except OSError:
            pass

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def print(self, text):
        print('From JS:', text)


app = QApplication([])
p = WebPage()
v = QWebEngineView()
v.setPage(p)
p.profile().scripts().insert(client_script())
c = QWebChannel(p)
p.setWebChannel(c)
c.registerObject('bridge', p)
v.setHtml('<p>Hello world!')
v.show()
app.exec_()
```

When I run the above code I get the console output:

```
Property 'selectedText'' of object 'WebPage' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!

Property 'hasSelection'' of object 'WebPage' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!

Property 'requestedUrl'' of object 'WebPage' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!

Property 'title'' of object 'WebPage' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
```

How do I define the properties to be constants?

Alternatively how can I attach a notify signal?
I tried:

```
self.titleChanged.connect(self.handleChange)

@pyqtSlot()
def handleChange(self):
    return
```

but the console messages still persist.

Comment: They all look CONSTANT to me: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/api/qwebenginepage.h.html

Mabye that got fixed between your version and the current code

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704128/undefined-properties-and-return-types-when-using-qwebchannel, and also [Support for Qt Properties](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt_properties.html).