# Qt 5.7 - QWebEngineView - Connect HTML button click event to C++/Qt Slot

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I am using Qt 5.7 QWebEngineView.

How to connect HTML button click event to a Q_SLOT on C++/PyQt5 side?

I can't find a clear example on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a bridge QObject, The mistake I ran into while implementing this class, was that I forgot to add `@QtCore.pyqtSlot` decorator, and it was important.

```
class Bridge(QtCore.QObject):
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def some_slot():
        print("Slot Invoked")
```

Here I created a `QWebEngineView` and a `QWebChannel` and set the web channel of the `QWebEnginePage` to be that channel and vice versa.

Then I created my Bridge QObject `self.helper_bridge` at first I didn't use `self` and just used `helper_bridge` by its own, and of course this made my app crash

```
class MainWidget(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(parent)

        channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel(self.webView.page())
        self.webView.page().setWebChannel(channel)

        self.helper_bridge = Bridge()
        channel.registerObject("helperBridge", self.helper_bridge)

        url = QtCore.QUrl("file:///path/to/index.html")
        self.webView().page().load(url)
        ...
```

At last, the `index.html` page,

Pay attention to the second script which is provided by Qt.

Here I created an instance of `QWebChannel` given my transport: `qt.webChannelTransport`, and inside the callback I handled the click event binding as you can see.

```
<html>                                                                          
    <head>                                                                        
    </head>                                                                       
    <body>                                                                        
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js'</script>
        <script src='qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js'></script>
      <h1>hello</h1>                                         
      <ul>                                                   
          <li>list item 1</li>                                                      
          <li>list item 2</li>                                                      
      </ul>                                                                       
      <a href='#go'>GO</a>                                                      
      <script>                                                                    
        $(document).ready(function(){
            new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel){            
                $('h1').on('click', function({
                    channel.objects.helperBridge.some_slot()
                });
            });
        });                                                                       
      </script>
  </body>
```

References:

- [QT QWebEnginePage::setWebChannel() transport object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928444/qt-qwebenginepagesetwebchannel-transport-object)
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-javascript.html