# Launch javascript function from pyqt QWebEngineView

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I'm planning on executing a javascript function from pyqt QWebEngine. I followed a example which was using a map and map bound were retrieved when a Qt application button was pushed, and wrote a small example.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

<script>
    function helloWorld(param1, param2) {
        return "Hello world " + param1 + " " + param2;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Python:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.form_widget = FormWidget(self)
        _widget = QWidget()
        _layout = QVBoxLayout(_widget)
        _layout.addWidget(self.form_widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(_widget)


class FormWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(FormWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__controls()
        self.__layout()
        self.browser.page().runJavaScript("helloWorld()", self.ready)

    def __controls(self):
        html = open('test.html', 'r').read()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setHtml(html)

    def __layout(self):
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.hBox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.hBox.addWidget(self.browser)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hBox)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

    def ready(self, returnValue):
        print(returnValue)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Nevertheless, I get the following error:

```
js: Uncaught ReferenceError: helloWorld is not defined
None ----> This is the return value printed at ready()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does `window.helloWorld()` work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

- You are calling the function when the page has not yet finished loading.
- Your function needs 2 parameters, although it also works but will signal *undefined*.

Using the above you get the following:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.form_widget = FormWidget(self)
        _widget = QWidget()
        _layout = QVBoxLayout(_widget)
        _layout.addWidget(self.form_widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(_widget)


class FormWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(FormWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__controls()
        self.__layout()

    def __controls(self):
        html = open('test.html', 'r').read()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setHtml(html)
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.onLoadFinished)

    def onLoadFinished(self, ok):
        if ok:
            self.browser.page().runJavaScript("helloWorld(1, \"2\")", self.ready)

    def __layout(self):
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.hBox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.hBox.addWidget(self.browser)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hBox)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

    def ready(self, returnValue):
        print(returnValue)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

**plus:**

To visualize the output of the js console you must overwrite the [`javaScriptConsoleMessage`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#javaScriptConsoleMessage) method of [`QWebEnginePage`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html):

```
...
class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, level, message, lineNumber, sourceID):
        print("javaScriptConsoleMessage: ", level, message, lineNumber, sourceID)


class FormWidget(QWidget):
    ...
    def __controls(self):
        ...
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setPage(WebEnginePage(self.browser))
        ...
```

To verify this you must use `console.log(...)`:

***.html**

```
...
<script>
    function helloWorld(param1, param2) {
        console.log("Hello world")
        return "Hello world " + param1 + " " + param2;
    }
</script>
...
```

Output:

```
javaScriptConsoleMessage:  0 Hello world 12 data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,%3C%21DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset%3D%22UTF-8%22%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%0A%3Cscript%3E%0A%20%20%20%20function%20helloWorld%28param1%2C%20param2%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09console.log%28%22Hello%20world%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%20world%20%22%20%2B%20param1%20%2B%20%22%20%22%20%2B%20param2%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E
```

Comment: That was my first thought, and tried using time.sleep(1). Maybe It wasnt enough. Your approach is much better, I Will try It later thanks :)

Comment: @RomanRdgz never use `time.sleep(...)` in a GUI since that function does not pause, if it does not block the GUI preventing other tasks from being executed.

Comment: do you happen to know if js console output is somehow accesible through the QWebEngineView? Otherwise I'll need to debut the js being blind

Comment: @RomanRdgz for debugging see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681141/qtwebengine-debugging).