PyQT5 WebEngineView no import of js files. Live Server with the same files works
The WebEngineView of pyQT5 does not import needed js modules. Here is a minimal example that runs normally in the Live Server of Visual Studio Code:
cube.html (works with Live Server, Demo from three.js as example)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Import Problem</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
</head>

<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "/js/three.module.js"
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'three'

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setAnimationLoop( animate );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {

    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
</script>
</body>
</html>

The pyQT5 app minimal example:
cube.py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings
import os
import sys

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QMainWindow()
browser = QWebEngineView()

html_path = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "cube.html")
link = QUrl.fromLocalFile(html_path)
browser.load(link)
central_widget = browser
w.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

ERROR:
js: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I have tried out all possible settings for the WebView. Switch off security. Local file Access on etc. Everthing allowed. Still no change.
Changing the location of the js makes no difference all paths and the QUrl are correct.
It seems that the path is not resolved no matter if in  or directly specified in the .
js/three.module.js ./js/three.module.js or three.module.js no change.
Of course you can simply set up a minimal server in python, but that is not an alternative for the project in this case.
System: Windows 11 with Python 3.12 and latest pyQT5.15
Any ideas?

Possibly related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69358171 In any case, using a server would be more reliable.
